# Jooq batch record insert

Tags: java, database, postgresql, bulkinsert, jooq

I'm currently trying to insert in batch many records (~2000) and Jooq's batchInsert is not doing what I want.

I'm transforming POJOs into UpdatableRecords and then I'm performing batchInsert which is executing insert for each record. So Jooq is doing ~2000 queries for each batch insert and it's killing database performance.

It's executing this code (jooq's batch insert):

```
for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
            Configuration previous = ((AttachableInternal) records[i]).configuration();

            try {
                records[i].attach(local);
                executeAction(i);
            }
            catch (QueryCollectorSignal e) {
                Query query = e.getQuery();
                String sql = e.getSQL();

                // Aggregate executable queries by identical SQL
                if (query.isExecutable()) {
                    List<Query> list = queries.get(sql);

                    if (list == null) {
                        list = new ArrayList<Query>();
                        queries.put(sql, list);
                    }

                    list.add(query);
                }
            }
            finally {
                records[i].attach(previous);
            }
        }
```

I could just do it like this (because Jooq is doing same thing internally):

```
records.forEach(UpdatableRecord::insert);
```

instead of:

```
jooq.batchInsert(records).execute();
```

How can I tell Jooq to create new records in batch mode? Should I transform records into bind queries and then call batchInsert? Any ideas? ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jOOQ's [`DSLContext.batchInsert()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#batchInsert-java.util.Collection-) creates one JDBC batch statement per set of consecutive records with identical generated SQL strings (the Javadoc doesn't formally define this, unfortunately).

This can turn into a problem when your records look like this:

```
+------+--------+--------+
| COL1 | COL2   | COL3   |
+------+--------+--------+
| 1*   | {null} | {null} |
| 2*   | B*     | {null} |
| 3*   | {null} | C*     |
| 4*   | D*     | D*     |
+------+--------+--------+
```

.. because in that case, the generated SQL strings will look like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO t (col1) VALUES (?);
INSERT INTO t (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?);
INSERT INTO t (col1, col3) VALUES (?, ?);
INSERT INTO t (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?);
```

The reason for this default behaviour is the fact that this is the only way to guarantee ... `DEFAULT` behaviour. As in SQL `DEFAULT`. [I gave a rationale of this behaviour here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/176595/2512).

With this in mind, and as each consecutive SQL string is different, the inserts unfortunately aren't batched as a single batch as you intended.

#### Solution 1: Make sure all changed flags are `true`

One way to enforce all `INSERT` statements to be the same is to set all changed flags of each individula record to `true`:

```java
for (Record r : records)
    r.changed(true);
```

Now, all SQL strings will be the same.

#### Solution 2: Use the `Loader` API

Instead of batching, you could import the data (and specify batch sizes there). For details, see the manual's section about importing records:

https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/importing/importing-records

#### Solution 3: Use a batch statement instead

Your usage of `batchInsert()` is convenience that works when using `TableRecords`. But of course, you can generate an `INSERT` statement manually and batch the individual bind variables by using jOOQ's batch statement API:

https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/batch-execution

#### A note on performance

There are a couple of open issues regarding the `DSLContext.batchInsert()` and similar API. The client side algorithm that generates SQL strings for each individual record is inefficient and might be changed in the future, relying on `changed()` flags directly. Some relevant issues:

- [#4533](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4533): DSLContext.batchInsert(), batchUpdate(), batchDelete(), etc. generate too many individual SQL statements
- [#6294](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6294): DSLContext.batchInsert() should take into consideration all Record.changed() flags

Comment: Solution 2 works. Jooq is creating bulk insert, however it doesnt speed up overall process. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @hya: Have you tried playing with the bulk, batch, and commit sizes?

Comment: Only with batch size. To change commit size, I'd need to disable autocommit. Maybe I'll try later.

Comment: @hya: Oh yes, you shouldn't commit each individual insert. Usually a commit size of 1000 rows can help on some databases.

Comment: @LukasEder if the records will always have all the value, will there be any performance issue

Comment: @SouravJha: The SQL query is being re-rendered for each record (because prior to rendering it, jOOQ doesn't *know* that it will be identical, even if all values are set on each record, e.g. due to custom data type `Binding`). But if this is an actual performance issue should be measured. It's just a SQL string generation, so it might be acceptable.

Comment: @LukasEuder: on db side this will be batch insert only correct?

Comment: @SouravJha: Whenever jOOQ uses the term *"batch"* in its API, it will attempt to translate that to JDBC batch where supported.

Comment: @LukasEder:
* is there some config to tune on size for batchXXX() APIs or we have to control by passing the appropriate size list?

Comment: @SouravJha: jOOQ 3.19 will let you use `Settings.batchSize` for all batch API: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14840. Before jOOQ 3.19, you have to split your list into chunks yourself, manually.