# Batching stores transparently

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, jooq

We are using the following frameworks and versions:

- `jOOQ 3.11.1`
- `Spring Boot 2.3.1.RELEASE`
- `Spring 5.2.7.RELEASE`

I have an issue where some of our business logic is divided into logical units that look as follows:

- Request containing a user transaction is received
- This request contains various information, such as the type of transaction, which products are part of this transaction, what kind of payments were done, etc.
- These attributes are then stored individually in the database.

In code, this looks approximately as follows:

```java
TransactionRecord transaction = transactionRepository.create();
transaction.create(creationCommand);`
```

In `Transaction#create` (which runs transactionally), something like the following occurs:

```java
storeTransaction();
storePayments();
storeProducts();
// ... other relevant information
```

A given transaction can have many different types of products and attributes, all of which are stored. Many of these attributes result in `UPDATE` statements, while some may result in `INSERT` statements - it is difficult to fully know in advance.

For example, the `storeProducts` method looks approximately as follows:

```java
products.forEach(product -> {
    ProductRecord record = productRepository.findProductByX(...);
    if (record == null) {
        record = productRepository.create();
        record.setX(...);
        record.store();
    } else {
      // do something else
    }
});
```

If the products are new, they are `INSERT`ed. Otherwise, other calculations may take place. Depending on the size of the transaction, this single user transaction could obviously result in up to `O(n)` database calls/roundtrips, and even more depending on what other attributes are present. In transactions where a large number of attributes are present, this may result in upwards of hundreds of database calls for a single request (!). I would like to bring this down as close as possible to `O(1)` so as to have more predictable load on our database.

Naturally, batch and bulk inserts/updates come to mind here. What I would like to do is to batch all of these statements into a single batch using `jOOQ`, and execute after successful method invocation prior to commit. I have found several ([SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45274242/jooq-batch-record-insert), [jOOQ API](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#batchStore%28java.util.Collection%29), [jOOQ GitHub Feature Request](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3419)) posts where this topic is implicitly mentioned, and [one user groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/RRAYf2OUO8U) that seemed explicitly related to my issue.

Since I am using `Spring` together with `jOOQ`, I believe my ideal solution (preferably declarative) would look something like the following:

```java
@Batched(100) // batch size as parameter, potentially
@Transactional
public void createTransaction(CreationCommand creationCommand) {
    // all inserts/updates above are added to a batch and executed on successful invocation
}
```

For this to work, I imagine I'd need to manage a scoped (`ThreadLocal`/`Transactional`/`Session` scope) resource which can keep track of the current batch such that:

1. Prior to entering the method, an empty batch is created if the method is `@Batched`,
2. A custom `DSLContext` (perhaps extending `DefaultDSLContext`) that is made available via DI has a `ThreadLocal` flag which keeps track of whether any current statements should be batched or not, and if so
3. Intercept the calls and add them to the current batch instead of executing them immediatelly.

However, step 3 would necessitate having to rewrite a large portion of our code from the (IMO) relatively readable:

```java
records.forEach(record -> {
    record.setX(...);
    // ...
    record.store();
}
```

to:

```java
userObjects.forEach(userObject -> {
    dslContext.insertInto(...).values(userObject.getX(), ...).execute();
}
```

which would defeat the purpose of having this abstraction in the first place, since the second form can also be rewritten using `DSLContext#batchStore` or `DSLContext#batchInsert`. IMO however, batching and bulk insertion should not be up to the individual developer and should be able to be handled transparently at a higher level (e.g. by the framework).

I find the readability of the `jOOQ` API to be an amazing benefit of using it, however it seems that it does not lend itself (as far as I can tell) to interception/extension very well for cases such as these. Is it possible, with the `jOOQ 3.11.1` (or even current) API, to get behaviour similar to the former with transparent batch/bulk handling? What would this entail?

---

EDIT:

One possible but extremely hacky solution that comes to mind for enabling transparent batching of stores would be something like the following:

1. Create a `RecordListener` and add it as a default to the `Configuration` whenever batching is enabled.
2. In `RecordListener#storeStart`, add the query to the current Transaction's batch (e.g. in a `ThreadLocal<List>`)
3. The `AbstractRecord` has a `changed` flag which is checked (`org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl#store0`, `org.jooq.impl.TableRecordImpl#addChangedValues`) prior to storing. Resetting this (and saving it for later use) makes the store operation a no-op.
4. Lastly, upon successful method invocation but prior to commit:

- Reset the `changes` flags of the respective records to the correct values
- Invoke `org.jooq.UpdatableRecord#store`, this time without the `RecordListener` or while skipping the `storeStart` method (perhaps using another `ThreadLocal` flag to check whether batching has already been performed).

As far as I can tell, this approach *should* work, in theory. Obviously, it's extremely hacky and prone to breaking as the library internals may change at any time if the code depends on Reflection to work.

Does anyone know of a better way, using only the public `jOOQ` API?

Comment: For the record, I posted this same question to the [jOOQ user group](https://groups.google.com/g/jooq-user/c/NYui2chcDc0). I most likely should have posted it there directly. I will update this post with any information I learn there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### jOOQ 3.14 solution

You've already discovered the relevant [feature request #3419](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3419), which will solve this on the JDBC level starting from jOOQ 3.14. You can either use the `BatchedConnection` directly, wrapping your own connection to implement the below, or use this API:

```java
ctx.batched(c -> {

    // Make sure all records are attached to c, not ctx, e.g. by fetching from c.dsl()
    records.forEach(record -> {
        record.setX(...);
        // ...
        record.store();
    }
});
```

#### jOOQ 3.13 and before solution

For the time being, until #3419 is implemented (it will be, in jOOQ 3.14), you can implement this yourself as a workaround. You'd have to proxy a JDBC `Connection` and `PreparedStatement` and ...

**... intercept all:**

- Calls to `Connection.prepareStatement(String)`, returning a cached proxy statement if the SQL string is the same as for the last prepared statement, or batch execute the last prepared statement and create a new one.
- Calls to `PreparedStatement.executeUpdate()` and `execute()`, and replace those by calls to `PreparedStatement.addBatch()`

**... delegate all:**

- Calls to other API, such as e.g. `Connection.createStatement()`, which should flush the above buffered batches, and then call the delegate API instead.

I wouldn't recommend hacking your way around jOOQ's `RecordListener` and other SPIs, I think that's the wrong abstraction level to buffer database interactions. Also, you will want to batch other statement types as well.

Do note that by default, jOOQ's `UpdatableRecord` tries to fetch generated identity values (see `Settings.returnIdentityOnUpdatableRecord`), which is something that prevents batching. Such `store()` calls must be executed immediately, because you might expect the identity value to be available.

Comment: Thanks so much for the extremely fast feedback, as well as for the hint with regard to fetching generated identity values; we'll have to weigh the options and see if we just swallow the 'bitter pill' and work with `DSLContext#batchStore` until we can update to `3.14`, as I'm sure there are various other little edge cases to consider. Thanks again!